# Wordpress theme git deployment to windows azure

Tags: wordpress, git, azure, themes, bitbucket

I need to set up continuous deployment of a WordPress theme that is source controlled on bit-bucket.

An external agency is managing the theme development.

The WordPress install is hosted on the Windows Azure platform.
I can set up continuous deployment from a number of git services, including bit-bucket, but Azure wants to set the deployment from site root, where I need to the deployment on at the themes folder level.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out all that is required is a .deployment file in the root of the repository

```
[config]
DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = D:\home\site\wwwroot\path\to\theme
```